# Extract PRORES Video with 5.1 audio from file with Mono and downmix

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a prores video with just 5.1 audio from a Prores with the below audio track layout. How can I do that using the FFmpeg library?

I could not figure out which command to use from the below ffmpeg library spec
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a2monostereo

Desired Output PRORES to contain below track layout

- track 0 - video (src Stream #0:0)
- track 1 - FL  (src Stream #0:1)
- track 2 - FR (src Stream #0:2)
- track 3 - FC (src Stream #0:3)
- track 4 - LFE (src Stream #0:4)
- track 5 - BL (src Stream #0:5)
- track 6 - BR (src Stream #0:6)
- track 7 - tmcd  (src Stream #0:8)

Below is the source video/audio Track Layout

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 171944 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:8(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-17T19:58:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      reel_name       :
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [channelmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelmap=channel_layout=FL[FL];[0:a:1]channelmap=channel_layout=FR[FR];[0:a:2]channelmap=channel_layout=FC[FC];[0:a:3]channelmap=channel_layout=LFE[LFE];[0:a:4]channelmap=channel_layout=BL[BL];[0:a:5]channelmap=channel_layout=BR[BR]" -map 0:v -map "[FL]" -map "[FR]" -map "[FC]" -map "[LFE]" -map "[BL]" -map "[BR]" -map d -c copy -c:a pcm_s24le output.mov
```

Comment: Hi llogan

this command is outputing 5.1 into single track, the desired output is as below.

track 0 - video (src Stream #0:0)
track 1 - FL  (src Stream #0:1)
track 2 - FR (src Stream #0:2)
track 3 - FC (src Stream #0:3)
track 4 - LFE (src Stream #0:4)
track 5 - BL (src Stream #0:5)
track 6 - BR (src Stream #0:6)
track 7 - tmcd  (src Stream #0:8)

Comment: Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 166533 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
      timecode        : 00:59:59:00
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 5.1, s32 (24 bit), 6912 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video M

Comment: @user2920456 It wasn't clear what you wanted in your original question so I had to guess. See updated answer.